# Python: How to update the JSON data in Python

Tags: python, json

The below input is the JSON Array. I am passing the below data to my Python method.

```
input={"details": [{"first": [
                         {"id": "111", "flag": "T", "planName": "PPO"},
                         {"id": "123", "flag": "F", "planName": "HMO"},
                         {"id": "133", "flag": "T", "planName": "MA"}],
         "second": [{"planName": "PPO", "planRank": "3"},
                     {"planName": "HMO", "planRank": "4"},
                     {"planName": "MA", "planRank": "7"}]}]}
```

The below is the JSON existing file,

```
final.json
    {"first": [{"id": "111", "flag": "T", "planName": "EPO"},
                {"id": "133", "flag": "T", "planName": "HMO"},
                {"id": "123", "flag": "T", "planName": "MA"}],
    "second": [{"planName": "PPO", "planRank": "1"},
                {"planName": "HMO", "planRank": "1"},
                {"planName": "MA", "planRank": "1"}]}
```

When I pass the above input data to my Python method the corresponding fields in the existing JSON files should get updated.From my input JSON when it matches with existing JSON of id then 'flag' and 'planname' should be updated with the passing values from input JSON.

and from second when it matches with 'planName' then PlanRank should be updated with new values passing from the input.

Expected Output(Existing JSON file should get the update like below):

```
final.json

    {"first": [{"id": "111", "flag": "T", "planName": "PPO"},
                {"id": "133", "flag": "T", "planName": "MA"},
                {"id": "123", "flag": "F", "planName": "HMO"}],
    "second": [{"planName": "PPO", "planRank": "3"},
               {"planName": "HMO", "planRank": "4"},
               {"planName": "MA", "planRank": "7"}]}
```

I have tried the below code but no luck.

```
def update_json():
    input={"details": [{"first": [
                             {"id": "111", "flag": "T", "planName": "PPO"},
                             {"id": "123", "flag": "F", "planName": "HMO"},
                             {"id": "133", "flag": "T", "planName": "MA"}],
             "second": [{"planName": "PPO", "planRank": "3"},
                         {"planName": "HMO", "planRank": "4"},
                         {"planName": "MA", "planRank": "7"}]}]}

    for x in input:

        property = open("final.json")
        data = json.load(property)
        for y in range(len(data)):
        for o in range(len(data['first'])):
            if (data['first'][o]['id'] == input[x][0]['id']):
                data['first'][o]['planName'] = input[x][0]['planName']
                data['first'][o]['flag'] = input[x][0]['flag']

        for j in range(len(data['second'])):
            print(data['details'][j])
            if (data['second'][j]['planName'] == input[x][0]['planName']):
                data['second'][j]['planRank'] = input[x][0]['planRank']
    with open(("final.json"), 'w') as file:

        value = json.dumps(data)
        file.write(value)

    return "value"
```

Comment: what about `input['details'][0]`?

Comment: It is not clear where your `data` object is being loaded. It looks like you are saving the data to a file after you update it and then return a string that just says `"value"`. Also, the input array is nested under the `details` key, so you may want to actually iterate through `for x in input['details']:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really shouldn't store anything to variable `input` as `input` is a builtin python function.

I tried my best to maintain your coding style.

This works for the above example:

```
def update_json():
    input_data = {"details": [{"first": [
                             {"id": "111", "flag": "T", "planName": "PPO"},
                             {"id": "123", "flag": "F", "planName": "HMO"},
                             {"id": "133", "flag": "T", "planName": "MA"}],
             "second": [{"planName": "PPO", "planRank": "3"},
                         {"planName": "HMO", "planRank": "4"},
                         {"planName": "MA", "planRank": "7"}]}]}

    with open('final.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    for x in input_data['details'][0]['first']:
        for y in range(len(data['first'])):
            if x['id'] == data['first'][y]['id']:
                data['first'][y]['planName'] = x['planName']
                data['first'][y]['flag'] = x['flag']

    for j in input_data['details'][0]['second']:
        for k in range(len(data['second'])):
            if j['planName'] == data['second'][k]['planName']:
                data['second'][k]['planRank'] = j['planRank']

    with open(("final.json"), 'w') as file:
        value = json.dumps(data)
        file.write(value)

    return value

update_json()
```

Comment: If I may ask being a student of python, why are your returning the value in the form `"value"` should it not be `value` so it can be used by a calling code?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I agree, it should be `value` and not `"value"`.  I forgot to update that when I posted this.  Updating now.  Thanks.